# Android drawText not showing the text

Tags: java, android

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
paint.setTextSize(20);
paint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(Typeface.BOLD));
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.setLinearText(true);
canvas.drawText(msgText, 200, 600, paint);
```

In my `View.onDraw()` method, I'am using this code, other shapes are drawen ok, but when I try to draw a text, nothing is showing, what is wrong in my code? android API > 15

Comment: Maybe the 200, 600 coordinates draws the text outside your canvas

Comment: @antonio, I've tried to set it to 0, 0, still the same, others shape are drawed at this coordinates...

Comment: use 0, 20 to be 100% sure

Comment: sorry to ask the obvious, but is msgText a non-empty string? Another problem might be the order in which you're drawing, try drawing the text last.